# itextsharp "razor to html" works fine but "to pdf" ignores styles

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, itext

I am wondering if itextsharp only accepts `<table>`. Is the problem using `<div>`s?

external css file below is invoked from the cshtml. Same code works fine to create html, fails with pdf. I am using `XMLWorkerHelper`.

RenderViewToString Method:

```
public class HtmlViewRenderer
{
    public string RenderViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object viewData)
    {
        var renderedView = new StringBuilder();
        using (var responseWriter = new StringWriter(renderedView))
        {
            var fakeResponse = new HttpResponse(responseWriter);
            var fakeContext = new HttpContext(HttpContext.Current.Request, fakeResponse);
            var fakeControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(fakeContext), controller.ControllerContext.RouteData, controller.ControllerContext.Controller);

            var oldContext = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpContext.Current = fakeContext;

            using (var viewPage = new ViewPage())
            {
                var html = new HtmlHelper(CreateViewContext(responseWriter, fakeControllerContext), viewPage);
                html.RenderPartial(viewName, viewData);
                HttpContext.Current = oldContext;
            }
        }

   return renderedView.ToString();
}
private static ViewContext CreateViewContext(TextWriter responseWriter, ControllerContext fakeControllerContext)
{
        return new ViewContext(fakeControllerContext, new FakeView(), new ViewDataDictionary(), new TempDataDictionary(), responseWriter);
}
}
```

StandardPdfRenderClass - Render Method:

```
public class StandardPdfRenderer
{
    private const int HorizontalMargin = 10;
    private const int VerticalMargin = 10;

    public byte[] Render(string htmlText, string pageTitle)
    {

        byte[] renderedBuffer;

        //BaseFont Vn_Helvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf", "Identity-H", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        BaseFont Vn_Helvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        Font fontNormal = new Font(Vn_Helvetica, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        using (var outputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A3, HorizontalMargin, HorizontalMargin, 110, 30))
            {
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, outputMemoryStream);
                pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
                pdfWriter.PageEvent = new PrintHeaderFooter();

                using (var htmlViewReader = new StringReader(TurkceKarakter(htmlText)))
                {
                   pdfDocument.Open(); 
                   XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, pdfDocument, htmlViewReader);
                    //used to be like this. Changed it to include XMLWorkerHelper up there.
                    //using (var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDocument))
                    //{                          
                    //    htmlWorker.Parse(htmlViewReader);
                    //}
                }
            }

            renderedBuffer = new byte[outputMemoryStream.Position];
            outputMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            outputMemoryStream.Read(renderedBuffer, 0, renderedBuffer.Length);
        }

        return renderedBuffer;
    }

    public string TurkceKarakter(string text)
    {

        text = text.Replace("İ", "I");
        text = text.Replace("ı", "i");
        text = text.Replace("Ş", "S");
        text = text.Replace("ş", "s");
        text = text.Replace("Ğ", "G");
        text = text.Replace("ğ", "g");
        text = text.Replace("Ö", "Ö");
        text = text.Replace("ö", "ö");
        text = text.Replace("ç", "c");
        text = text.Replace("Ç", "C");
        text = text.Replace("ü", "ü");
        text = text.Replace("Ü", "Ü");
        return text;
    }
}
```

Here is the cshtml:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
<div id="maincontent">        
    <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_1_of_1">
            <div class="baslik"><span class="mavi">.</span><h3>CV</h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_1_of_2">
            <div> 
                <img src="@(helper.StaticUrl + helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.Resim)" width="180" alt="Resim" />                       
            </div>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div class="col span_1_of_1 clearfix">
            <div class="isim">
                <span class="adisoyadi">@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.AdiSoyadi.ToUpper())</span> 
                               </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="col span_1_of_2 clearfix">
            <dl class="iletisim">
                <dt class="uk-icon-mobile">Telefon</dt>
                <dd>@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.CepTelefonUlkeKod) @(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.CepTelefon) </dd>
                <dt class=" uk-icon-email">E-mail</dt>
                <dd>@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.Email)</dd>
                <dt class="uk-icon-adres">Adres</dt>
                <dd>@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.Adres) </dd>
                <dt class="uk-icon-adres">Doğum Tarihi</dt>
                <dd>@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.DogumTarihi)</dd>
                <dt class="uk-icon-adres">Medeni Durum</dt>
                <dd>@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.MedeniDurum)</dd>
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.AskerlikDurum))
                {
                    <dt class=" uk-icon-adres">Askerlik</dt>
                    <dd>@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.AskerlikDurum)</dd>
                }
                <dt class="uk-icon-adres">Çalışma Durumu</dt>
                <dd>@(helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.CalismaDurum.HasValue ? helper.Detay.Detay.GenelBilgi.CalismaDurum.Value ? "Çalışıyor" : "Çalışmıyor" : "")</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>          
        <div class="col span_1_of_1 aciklama">              
        </div>
    </div>   
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'd guess you aren't serving up styles for the print medium, only screen.

Comment: What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Try serving up some styles for the print medium e.g. `<style type="text/css" media="print" />` See if they present themselves in the PDF.

Comment: Can you post the iTextSharp part of the code and what "fails" means? Also, from iTextSharp's perspective there is no ASP.Net, MVC or Razor, there's only HTML and CSS so you'll want to investigate the raw HTML that you are passing into iTextSharp.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I edited the answer. Added RenderViewToString and Render methods.

Comment: iTextSharp's XMLWorker is in no way a full HTML/CSS renderer and I don't think it ever will be (just my personal guess). Thing like `:before` and `:after` probably won't work. `@font-face` won't either, although it probably wouldn't be too hard to download the TTF files manually. You can use multiple CSS classes, too, but I don't think the selectors have been implemented, so no `>`, `+` or ``[class*='uk-icon-']``. All of your parsing code looks correct, you're just expecting more of the HTML and CSS than it can handle.

Comment: Basically, you are saying it's not possible to export html to pdf as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it for very basic html to pdf, but even their site says that the xml worker is really meant to be a template system. [itext functionality comparison](http://itextpdf.com/functionalitycomparison). It really has no support for advanced layouts, etc... I ran up against this recently on a project that I'm part of and why I started investigating different tools such as the one below.

If you have the ability to use a different tool, you could try using a library like [TuesPechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin) which is a .net wrapper for wkhtmltopdf. Wkhtmltopdf uses the QT Webkit rendering engine and has robust support for html5/css3.